# Cordova overwriting JS based on platform

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

So I have to override some stuff using JS in cordova app. I have to write something different for IOS and something else for Android. Is there a way to do that in Cordova?

I am using visual studio cordova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the merges folder

You create a new .js for ios and put all the ios specific js there, then copy it to merges/ios
Then, you create a new .js with the same name for android and put all the android specific js there, then copy it to merges/android

When you do a `cordova prepare ios` all the files on merges/ios will be copied to the ios www folder, and if you do a `cordova prepare android` the files on merges/android will be copied to the android www folder